# NSTextAligment applying only after editing textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I create table view cell which contains my custom text field, subclass of UITextField. When i add text field to my cell i set

```
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

I have placeholder on text field. When my cell appears it's alignment is something average between left and center. Then after editing it becoming center. I need center alignment right after creating cell. Can anyone help to solve this?

**Edit**

My CellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (CTKMultiColumnTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.section];
    CTKMultiColumnTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CTKMultiColumnTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        [cell setFrameWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 34)];
    }
    cell.textField.placeholder = [_placeholders objectAtIndex:tableView.tag];
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.relatedTableView = tableView;

    return cell;
}
```

and part of willDisplayCell method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CTKMultiColumnTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (tableView.tag) {

        case 4:
            cell.textField.leftView = nil;
            cell.textField.rightView = nil;
            cell.textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
            cell.isPickable = NO;
            cell.valueLimitMin = 0;
            cell.valueLimitMax = 1000;

            if (((CTKRoom *)[_roomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]).heatedArea) {
                cell.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ((CTKRoom *)[_roomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]).heatedArea];
            }
            else cell.textField.text = @"";
            break;


}
```

this part is example of setting properties to my cell

Comment: Can you show how you create your cell ? Maybe your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: try to set `textAlignment` in YourTextField's `init` method

Comment: @Seryozha i cant do it in TextField init method because i use this TextField in many different tables but need center alignment only in one.

Comment: Have you tried setting the alignment in cellForRowAtIndexPath, before setting the placeholder ? The weird part is about "average between left and center" you do realize that if your placeholder is long it will start somewhere between left and center, right ?

Comment: I tried to set alignment before setting the placeholder - problem wasn't solved. It doesn't matter length of placeholder - it starts between left and center.

Comment: Maybe provide an image, make sure your uitextfield is also centered in your cell.

Comment: The reason was in my rightView and his mode UITextFieldViewModeAlways

Comment: Post it as an anwser and accept it, it can be helpful for other users.

Comment: A bit later, my rep is too low to do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The reason was

```
myTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

In my case right view was necessary, so in case when it wasn't needed i set

```
myTextField.rightView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 0);
```